# How to avoid error 'Unexpected token <' with a React app when running babel from a CDN?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am new to React and would at the moment like to run everything using CDNs. It seems that similar questions to avoid the same error I am getting ("Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <") are solved by including ''. But that is not working in this example when I run this very basic React app. Does it not work because Babel cannot transcompile the script from this same file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <body>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.7.7/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel"></script>
    <div id="app"></div>

</head>
<body>
<script>
    console.log('App.js is running!');
    var Template = (
        <div>
            <h1>John</h1>
            <p>Age: 26</p>
            <p>Location: Philadelphia</p>
        </div>
    )
    var AppRoot = document.getElementById('app')
    ReactDOM.render(Template, AppRoot)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `type='text/babel'` to your script. I also recommend to use at least react 16 if you want to start learning. You might also want to make sure to use UMD versions of react and reactDOM to make sure they run in the browser.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>First React App</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='app'></div>

  <script type='text/babel'>
console.log('App.js is running!');
var Template = (
    <div>
        <h1>John</h1>
        <p>Age: 26</p>
        <p>Location: Philadelphia</p>
    </div>
)
var AppRoot = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(Template, AppRoot)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I did have it in there, just not in the right location?

Comment: You had two errors in your script: the 'text/babel' type should be in the script tag that contains the code you want to transpile, and the second one is that your div with the id of 'app' was in your head which will cause it not to be shown in the browser even if babel transpiled your code.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>First React App</title>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='app'></div>

  <script type='text/babel'>
console.log('App.js is running!');

class Template extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>John</h1>
        <p>Age: 26</p>
        <p>Location: Philadelphia</p>
    </div>
    )
  }
}

//ReactDom function starting

var AppRoot = document.getElementById('app')
ReactDOM.render(<Template/>, AppRoot)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Use Reactjs version 16. Create `class-based` component then `render` it. Use this documentary for better understanding. [Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html)